# Is there a special file where clang++ store additional arguments? (Mac OS X)

Tags: c++, clang, macports

I recently uninstalled macports to replace it with homebrew. However, since then, I get a weird warning when I compile some C++ code

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'
```

That is the old directory path of macport that has been deleted. However that option has never been specified. I call the following lines

```
clang++ -c -W -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ src/main.cpp -o obj/main.o
clang++ -stdlib=libc++ obj/main.o -o bin/myprog-debug
```

I checked the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it is empty. So, where does that library path come from?

Comment: a dirty solution is `mkdir /opt/local/lib`

Comment: That's probably what I'll end up doing if I don't find a solution :)

Comment: Yes, on Mac OS X to be more exact (from the terminal).